# Setting limit for matplotlib colormap outside plt

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am currently using python matplotlib to 
convert a set of features to a visual representation using the colormap `cm.jet` and store them as numpy.ndarrays.. Problem is that I am not able to set vmin and vmax as i want..

what I am currently is doing is

```
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import matplotlib
>>> from matplotlib import cm
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> a = np.random.randint(5,size=(3,3))
>>> convert = plt.get_cmap(cm.jet)
>>> numpy_a = convert(a)
>>> numpy_a_limited = convert(a)
```

Problem is that matplotlib auto adjust the colorange, given the dataset, meaning that the pixel information of the stored numpy.ndarray is incorrect.

I am trying to fix the colorrange, such that the pixel information, becomes  relatable to the original data..

this is my attempt of trying to fixing the colorrange.

```
convert = plt.get_cmap(cm.jet)
        convert = convert.set_clim(vmin=-6, vmax=2)
```

Gives my error message:

```
AttributeError: 'LinearSegmentedColormap' object has no attribute 'set_clim'
```

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory. What do you want to achieve? Can you show a [mcve] or explain in detail your approach that would make it necessary to put limits on a colormap (which isn't possible btw.).

Comment: I added some details about my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to use a colormap, the range of values to must be between 0 and 1. Values outside this range are truncated, resulting in a loss in dynamic range of the values.

So you need to normalize your array prior to supplying it to the colormap. An option would be to use your custom normalization function

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randint(5,size=(3,3))
cmap = plt.cm.jet
norm = lambda x: (x+2.)/(6.+2.)
converted_a = cmap(norm(a))
```

The other option is to use a built-in Normalize instance

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randint(5,size=(3,3))
cmap = plt.cm.jet
norm = Normalize(vmin=-2, vmax=6)
converted_a = cmap(norm(a))
```